# loop array to show array string repeated nth times

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

Using array below, I need a loop to get specific result given below:

```js
var arr = ["ABCDE", "BCDEF", "BACDF", "ACDLK", "ABDCDE", "CDCDE"];
```

Every time repeat while array result with one space. The results should look like this:

```js
["ABCDE", "BCDEF", "BACDF", "ACDLK", "ABDCDE", "CDCDE", "ABCDE ", "BCDEF ", "BACDF ", "ACDLK ", "ABDCDE ", "CDCDE ", "ABCDE  ", "BCDEF  ", "BACDF  ", "ACDLK 
 ", "ABDCDE  ", "CDCDE  "]
```

Comment: What's your question? What have you tried? What are you having difficulty with?

Comment: Do you want to repeat the array 3 times?

Comment: i need array repeated 5times with one space added after 1 to each of string, 2 spaces after second and so on

Comment: yes som shekhar Mukharjee, but with space on each string after first and 2 space after second time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a closure and add the suffix to the values.

```js
const
    suffix = '*',
    getArray = (array, length) => Array
        .from(
            { length },
            (_, i) => array.map(s => s + suffix.repeat(i))
        )
        .flat(),
    result = getArray(['a', 'b', 'c'], 4);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: the third time string should be with 2 spaces

Comment: just add another space. please see edit.

Comment: but then it will come on all time, i mean to say that on 1repeat it should be one space and on second repeat it should be 2 spaces and so on

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: ["ABCDE", "BCDEF", "BACDF", "ACDLK", "ABDCDE", "CDCDE", "ABCDE ", "BCDEF ", "BACDF ", "ACDLK ", "ABDCDE ", "CDCDE ", "ABCDE  ", "BCDEF  ", "BACDF  ", "ACDLK  ", "ABDCDE  ", "CDCDE  "]

Comment: this should be the result @nina scholz

Comment: thanks to sangeet from Daffodil Software
https://stackexchange.com/users/21512999/sangeeta-rajput

Comment: thanks nina for your comments